# Declaration of a method in java programming

Tags: java, spring, class, oop, methods

I am going through already written code. I am not understanding  what is this

```
public classname methodname()
{
  //something
}
```

In which case above pattern is used in java programming?

Comment: Almost all the time. the **classname** is the return type and **methodname** is the name of your method.

Comment: this is your code? it's standing in this way in your code? or it's a comment?

Comment: It is used everywhere you can find OOP. I would suggest to open a guide for Java if you need to understand what it means.

Comment: You can also take a look at the feature `co-variant return type` in java, which will help you understand this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public String toString() {

    return "hello world";
}
```

`String` here is return type, it can be primitive type, or Class, or `void`. `void` means no return.
`toString` here is method name, it can be any word you like, but can't start with number or special characters. We recommend method name start with alphabet character. Refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) for details.
Codes in `{}` are functional method body, add codes you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about a pattern, then a briefly explanation is this:

**classname** it's the returned type of the method. So if you method it's returning an Object, then in the signature in the **classname** placeholder you should put Object.

**methodname** it's the name of the method. Every method must have a name and a return type.

It will help you if you read some basic java tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a method of name *methodname*, without parameters, which as a result returns an object of class *classname*.

Which is fairly frequent.